# Tracking S&P in Germany

Tags: stocks, germany, standard-and-poors-500

I would like to buy stocks that track the S&P500 in Germany (German citizen - I live and pay taxes in Germany).

If I was in the US, I would probably go for an ETF like VOO (Vanguard S&P 500 ETF) or IVV (iShares Core S&P500), because they track the index well, they have low expense ratios, and they are not too small in terms of volume.

I suppose one could use a traditional stock-market broker in Germany to buy VOO or IVV at a fee. So I have two questions: 
(i) Is there a cheaper way to buy and sell VOO or IVV shares directly in Germany?
(ii) Are there German funds that track the S&P500 at better rate?

Comment: Please clarify whether you are only subject to German taxes as, for example, if you were a US citizen living in Germany, it would be financially disadvantageous to invest in a German financial instrument tracking the S&P 500

Comment: @Eric: Good question. Yes, I am only subject to taxes in Germany

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are numerous companies offering ETFs that conform to EU regulations ([UCITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undertakings_for_Collective_Investment_in_Transferable_Securities_Directive_2009)); among the largest active in Germany are iShares, Lyxor, db x-trackers, ComStage, and Vanguard. (Note that some of these are active in the US, too, but their ETFs differ between jurisdictions.) Every single of these companies has at least one ETF tracking the S&P 500 in their portfolio, it’s absolutely standard. Some may additionally offer variants, such as currency hedged ETFs.

Comment: A good site to search for available ETFs and special offers (like free monthly investing plans) is [justETF](https://www.justetf.com/de/find-etf.html?groupField=index&index=S%2526P%2B500%25C2%25AE).

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what brokers are available in Germany nor do I know what commissions they  charge. Look into Interactive Brokers which is available in many countries and has very low commission rates.

Other  possibilities are Schwab who offers 200+ commission free ETFs (various issuers) and TDAmeritrade with 300+ no fee ETFs.  You'd have to do a little grunt work to determine if any correlate directly to  the S&P 500, if their expense ratios are competitive with the SPY which would be the benchmark, and if there are any  restrictions (time held).